# How to call a react component from another component and pass required props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, react-props

At the moment, I have the following routes in my `App.js` file:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/new-job"
          render={(props) => <NewJob jobName={jobName} setMenuSelection={handleMenuSelection} />}
  />
  <Route exact path="/past-jobs"
          render={(props) => <PastJobs setMenuSelection={handleMenuSelection} />}
 />
</Switch>
```

Now within my `PastJobs` component, I have the following button with onClick process:

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
      setConfirmDialog({
         isOpen: true,
         title: `Copy Job ${item.id}?`,
         onConfirm: () => { onCopy(item.job_info) }
      })
   }}         
>
Copy
</Button>
```

that calls the following function:

```
const onCopy = (job_info) => {
    setConfirmDialog({
        ...confirmDialog,
        isOpen: false
    })
    history.push({
        pathname: '/new-job',
        state: { detail: job_info }
    })
}
```

Within my `<NewJob />` component, I have now setup the following as I thought I could access the state.detail but unfortunately it's null, i.e.:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function NewJob( { jobName, setMenuSelection } ) {
    
       const { state } = useLocation();
    
       if (typeof state !== 'undefined') {
         const myVal = state.detail
         console.log("myVal", myVal )
       }
    
}
```

The issue that I am having and unsure how to approach is that within my onCopy function that is called from button onClick, how do I call the the `<NewJob />` component whose path is `exact path="/new-job"` in App.js above and pass in the prop `job_info` ?

Comment: You could make the info available within a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: @Reyno - new to React and unsure what you mean exactly

Comment: You can not "call" a component. You can add a component to another components return-statement. Use an if-statement to determine whether it should be included in the return-statement or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct calls to components actually does not exist. But what you are looking can be achieved in different ways.

1. Using state machine with event bus (redux, redux-saga)
2. Render props https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html
3. Bunch of callbacks drilled via props (HOC's)
4. Ref's https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

I suggest to read more about them to actually understand if it matches your use case. Anyhow it is great experience to develop your skills also!

Comment: Managed to get it working with render props as per updated code above.